# Get original object property stored in DB with Hibernate in same transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate

I opened hibernate transaction and read the object. I changed some properties of object without store. I want to get the original properties stored in DB but with

```
Criteria cr = new Criteria(...);
cr.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
cr.setProjection(Projections.property("someProperty"));
cr.uniqueResult();
```

or reload whole object with `getSession().get(id)`. But as a result I got changed properties and  if I reload whole object I got the same instance of changed object. How to get original object properties stored in DB with same transaction, changed object must remain with changed properties.
And how to do it with Spring transaction annotations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use session.refresh() method. See documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-loading

But this will overwrite any changes. You can clone the object before `refresh`, i think.

Comment: and how to store object after that?

Comment: Which object? If you want to persist the cloned object, you have to call `entityManager.merge(clonedObject)`, because it will be in `DETACHED` state.

Comment: By the way, any changes made to persistent objects will be reflected to database when you commit your transaction. The required `insert` and `update` statements will be called automatically by Hibernate. So you don't have to store it yourself.